# Return one to two column values depending upon existence of data in either column

Tags: excel

I'm trying to come up with a way to return a value in column D that indicates if columns B or C has HIFCA or HIDTA present. Ideally, it would either return a CONCAT string of, 'HIFCA,HIDTA' without the single quotes or just 'HIFCA' or 'HIDTA' if only a single value is present across the two columns.

I've looked at VLOOKUPs, COLUMN and other approaches from S/O and the Goog but nothing thus far matches my need.

Example Data:

```
Zip Codes   HIFCA   HIDTA
00501       HIFCA   HIDTA
00544       HIFCA   HIDTA
00601               HIDTA
00602               HIDTA
00603               HIDTA
00604               HIDTA
00605               HIDTA
```

Ideal Data:

```
Zip Codes   HIFCA   HIDTA   HIDTA_HIFCA_CHK
00501       HIFCA   HIDTA     HIFCA,HIDTA
00544       HIFCA   HIDTA     HIFCA,HIDTA
00601               HIDTA     HIDTA
00602               HIDTA     HIDTA
00603               HIDTA     HIDTA
00604               HIDTA     HIDTA
00605               HIDTA     HIDTA
00606       HIFCA   HIDTA     HIFCA,HIDTA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will return what you would like if you put it in Column D if either Column B or C are blank:

```
=IF(OR(B1="",C1=""),B1&C1,B1&","&C1)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! If I could up vote you I would.

Comment: You should be able to mark the answer correct (under the up/down vote arrows). Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Rather difficult to tell what you want given the formatting (and `00606` etc) but if `00501` is in A2 maybe try:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),C2,B2&","&C2)
```

in D2 and copy down to suit.